# how to display image from gridview using fragment after i run the program?

Tags: android, fragment

When I try to execute the code and run it then it does not display any code.

Here is my **adapter** code:

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    public MyAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) { // if it's not recycled, initialize some
                                    // attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        return imageView;
    }

    // references to our images
    private Integer[] mThumbIds = { R.drawable.buttonwi01,
            R.drawable.buttonwi02, R.drawable.buttonwi03,
            R.drawable.buttonwi04, R.drawable.buttonwi05,
            R.drawable.buttonwi06, R.drawable.buttonwi07, };
```

and my **fragment** class.

```
public class WallPaperFragment extends Fragment {

    private GridView gridView;
    private ImageView imageView;

    public WallPaperFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_wallpaper, container,
                false);
        GridView gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(view.getContext())); // uses the view
                                                                // to get the
                                                                // context
                                                                // instead of
                                                                // getActivity().
        return view;

    }
```

I cant display my images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to return correct size of images array

```
@Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }
```